# jquery 1.6.1 - selecting xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-9

In jquery 1.4.2 i was able to select xml residing in my html page by doing the following:

```
var xmlSettings = $("#xmlSettings")[0];
```

this is the same as:

```
document.getElementById("xmlSettings"); //this still works fine
```

In jquery 1.6.1 xmlSettings is undefined. all i did was upgrade my jquery from 1.4.2 to 1.6.1 and now this is not working.

is there a different selection that i need to do, or do i need to add a plugin?

xml in Html page:

```
<xml id="xmlSettings">
 <items>
        <item name="Test1">Test data 1</item>
        <item name="Test2">Test data 2</item>
        <item name="Test3">Test data 3</item>
 </items>
</xml>
```

thanks in advance,

[Resolved] Thanks to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

the problem seems to be one of the following:

1) IE9 is not rendering IE8 Standards mode properly.
   I just recently upgraded to IE9 but my app still needs to run in IE8 Standard Mode therefore I've forced it in IIS to render in IE8 using X-UA-Compatible IE=8

2) i also updated my jquery file from 1.4.2 to 1.6.1

but it could be a combination of these things i'm not really sure anyway using normal `document.getElementById("xmlSettings");` still works fine so in the mean time i'll use that but very bizarre issue. i wouldn’t be surprised if it's an IE9 issue. Or maybe i'll remain on jquery 1.4.2 for now.

Comment: XML inside HTML is invalid...

Comment: @Felix Kling, please will you kindly elaborate on your comment above? because according DOM this is fine

Comment: @superbDeveloper: Have you ever validated your HTML document? [HTML has a well defined set of allowed elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html). Also HTML parses don't expect anything else than these and it is probably undefined what they do with those tags.

Comment: if XML inside HTML is invalid, how come i can select this using normal `document.getElementById("xmlSettings");` ? there's absolutely nothing wrong with this because DOM allows it.

Comment: @superbDeveloper: DOM is not HTML. You can represent HTML as DOM. That does not make everything that is valid in DOM valid in HTML. That browsers still parse it and add it to them is probably because they try to compensate errors. But it is still wrong. You can validate your page here: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @Felix Kling ok getting back to my original question which concerns jquery 1.6.1 and 1.4.3 why does this `$("#xmlSettings");` selection not work when this `document.getElementById("xmlSettings");` selection does? to put thing in perspective the same selection `$("#xmlSettings");` in jquery 1.4.3 worked fine? is there a problem in 1.6.1 or what? why did it stop working in 1.6.1?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Em2Yq/ (in 1.6.1) Maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Felix Kling you are a legend buddy the Problem is IE9 running in Document Mode: IE8 standards. when i tried to reproduce this in FireFox it works. thanks again

Comment: @superbDeveloper: See, so maybe it is related to the fact that XML is not valid here and this mode might ignore these elements (again, maybe, I have a Mac, I cannot test it actually, just guessing here ;)).

Comment: @Felix Kling the problem is IE9. I just recently upgraded to IE9 the problem is i need to run the my app in IE8 Standard Mode but for reason IE9 is not rendering IE8 Standard Mode correctly therefore that’s why its breaking now or it could a combination of Jquery 1.6.1 I’m not really sure but at least i know it’s a browser issue. thanks again for your help

Comment: If you've resolved it please post the answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the real reason it's not working: a [regression in jQuery 1.4.2](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10003).

Comment: thanks for answering. i think its a combination of both, IE9 and JQuery. because when you run http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Em2Yq/ in normal IE mode all works fine. as soon you change Document Mode to IE8 it doesn't find the xml element.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the [0] because an id is a singular value and doesn't return an object list like finding a class would.

Comment: `$("#xmlSettings")` always returns a jQuery object. `$("#xmlSettings")[0]` gives you the first DOM element. In case of an ID selector, the jQuery object only contains one element, but the syntax is correct. A jQuery object is like an array.

Comment: yes i know that a jquery object is like an array. the problem is the jquery selection does not find the DOM element which is bit bizarre because it works fine in 1.4.3 but not in 1.6.1. Currently the length of `$("#xmlSettings")` is 0 it should be 1.

Comment: I really didn't think when I wrote that, what a muppet. You're right.

Comment: no problem buddy thanks for at least looking at my question and trying to assist. i really appreciate it buddy thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question as suggested by [Arend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779324/arend)

[Resolved] Thanks to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

the problem seems to be one of the following:

1) IE9 is not rendering IE8 Standards mode properly. I just recently upgraded to IE9 but my app still needs to run in IE8 Standard Mode therefore I've forced it in IIS to render in IE8 using X-UA-Compatible IE=8. Also another thing about X-UA-Compatible rather use IE=EmulateIE8 **not** IE=8. But still even when you use IE=EmulateIE8 it still does not play nicely with jquery 1.6.1. Therefore its better to use IE9 standard mode which works fine, so busy converting code to be standard be compliant anyway better in the long run.

2) i also updated my jquery file from 1.4.2 to 1.6.1

but it could be a combination of these things i'm not really sure anyway using normal `document.getElementById("xmlSettings");` still works fine so in the mean time i'll use that but very bizarre issue. i wouldn’t be surprised if it's an IE9 issue. Or maybe i'll remain on jquery 1.4.2 for now.